# Stretching in the morning

Tags: exercise, muscle

I commonly stretch first thing in the morning. However, I have heard that stretching without exercising beforehand can be bad for my muscles. Is this true?

Comment: I have L5-S1 injury because not stretching properly done before lifting weights. Always warmup your body parts, set your goal which body part you are training, warm it up first and then do the sets, reps. Streching daily is a good sign to start any training or lifting.

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/28227/19738 that might answer your question